# Issue with mage-messages cookie in iphone safari

Tags: magento2, cookie, messages, notification, iphone

For my device testing (iPhone Safari), multiple notifications pop on,

from the code `message.js`

```
initialize: function () {
        this._super();

        this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text')[_.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text').length-1];

        this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
            disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
        });

        if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
            customerData.set('messages', {});
        }

        $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');

        // $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
        //     $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
        // });

    }
```

Although I am setting `mage-messages` as empty at the end

```
$.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
```

Still, on the next reload the very first line of code gives me the old `mage-messages` message

```
$.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages')
```

This issue only prevails in iPhone safari, works fine in desktop `safari` and `chrome`.

How to resolve that issue, from where does that previous cookieStorage are getting set even if I am clearing it the at the end of my script.

And why does that issue only happening in iPhone device